# Ubuntu for Android phones

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a oneplus 2 and I was wondering about installing Ubuntu OS on it ...
Is it recommended or not ? 
And how can I do it if yes ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a rom for oneplustwo https://devices.ubports.com/#/op2

Answer (score 0):

You have the full list of Ubuntu Touch devices, compatibility and links [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices). There are a couple good oneplus links.